# Asymptotic behaviour of a recurrence relation - How to solve

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm going over a chapter in recurrence relations in preparation for job interviews and came across the following.
I'd like to gain some better understanding of how to solve such a question.

Find a function **F(*n*)**, that satisfies the recurrence **F(*n*) = 2F($\sqrt{n}$) +1** for all *n* $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

Then how do I find a big-O estimation for **F(*n*)**?

Answer (score 3):

There is no function that satisfies the conditions for $n \in \mathbb N$ since not all $\mathbb N$ have a square root.  However you can generalize to $n \in \mathbb R$:

Try constructing a function $G$ in terms of $F$, the common choices are:

$$G(n) = F(n^2)$$
$$G(n) = F(2^n)$$
$$G(n) = F(\log_2 n)$$
$$G(n) = F(\sqrt{n})$$

However, for this problem, the best these choices will get you is that one of them will give you $G(n)$ in terms of $G(n/2)$:

> $$G(n) = F(2^n) = 2F(\sqrt{2^n}) + 1 = 2F(2^{n/2}) + 1 = 2G(n/2) + 1$$

So repeating the process, we choose:

$$H(n) = G(?? n ??)$$

in such a way that $H(n)$ can be written in terms of $H(n - 1)$.

> $$H(n) = G(2^n) = 2G(2^n / 2) + 1 = 2G(2^{n - 1}) + 1 = 2H(n - 1) + 1$$

Now you solve the recursion for $H$, and use that to find $G$, and use that to find $F$.

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel.
How would I solve for H when there is no base case though?
Do I not need, say, H(1) = 1 or something similar?

Comment: @StrangeLoop Reread the question.  If it didn't give you a base case, then it is probably asking for asymptotic behavior, like "big O" notation.  Asymptotic behavior (except for edge cases) doesn't depend on initial conditions.

Comment: Ah I haven't experience with working out the big O of a recurrence relation, only on actual algorithms. Could you give a short breakdown of what I should do next in order to solve this?

Comment: @StrangeLoop Yes.  You should read the question carefully, edit your post to be the *exact* question, then learn the what the question is asking for.  Because the first step to solving the problem is understanding the question.

Comment: @StrangeLoop This site is not an appropriate for a lecture on Big O notation, but if you look around I'm sure you'll find explanations.  Honestly I can't give you any since I've always understood Big O intuitively, and can't really empathize well with someone who has to learn it from scratch.  Anyway this might help after you learn the basics:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Comment: With regards to applying the Master Theorem, would you have to go further than G(n) = 2G(n/2) + 1 stage? What is the advantage of repeating the process using H(n) = G(2^n) ?

Comment: No (good observation) and H(n) let's you find an exact closed form assuming reals instead of integers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was trying to show him how to arrive at that "epiphany" substitution in a reasoned fashion.

Comment: Very sorry about getting in your way, Daniel. I should've read the chain of comments more carefully. Well, the original poster has not visited the site since January 11, so I just delete the spoiler comment.